# How i can solve this kind of error in sqlite database E/SQLiteLog(16449): (1) near "Order": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I'm Trying to create another Table to sqlite database to insert fresh data from json link and all of a sudden i'm stack this kind of error i already do some uninstall and install of my app, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is my db dart file.

```
//Creating Table and opening of my db
initDB() async {
      String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'dbdev.db');
      return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {
      },onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE sku_table("
        "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        "ShortCode TEXT NULL,"
        "CampaignShortCode TEXT NULL,"
        "Code TEXT NULL,"
        "Name TEXT NULL,"
        "IsActive BOOL NULL,"
        "GenericName TEXT NULL,"
        "Level INTEGER NULL);",
      );
          //here where my error is
      await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE RegisterTabs("
          "RegId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
          "SortOrder INTEGER NULL,"
          "CampaignShortCode TEXT NULL,"
          "Order INTEGER NULL,"
          "ItemList TEXT NULL,"
          "Note TEXT NULL,"
          "IsActive BOOL NULL,"
          "IsRequired BOOL NULL,"
          "Label TEXT NULL,"
          "Key TEXT NULL,"
          "Tag TEXT NULL,"
          "InputType TEXT NULL,"
          "MaxLength INTEGER NULL,"
          "MinLength INTEGER NULL,"
          "Hint TEXT NULL,"
        "Delimiter TEXT NULL);",
      );
    }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Order` is an [sqlite keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). It's the easiest just to rename the column to something else, for example `OrderNo`.

Comment: I see Thank you bro, really appreciated.